# XFCE with Nemo: Context menu -> open in terminal does not work anymore

Tags: command-line, xfce, nemo

I don't know what I have touched, but now in my xfce desktop, both in folder and in files, I cannot run "open terminal" from right-click menu.

> NOTE: I am using Nemo as File Manager

Right-Clicking on a file or on a folder, the item 'Open in terminal' / 'Open terminal here' is no more present.

Right-clicking on the whyte space of file manager (nemo) I see 'open terminal', but it doesn't work.

I'd like to restore the original behaviour.

Could you kindly explain me how?

I already tried on Settings->default applications->utility->terminal emulator to change the selection. Nothing changes. Is a reboot needed? (it's a server, so it's quite complicated just "reboot to try")

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't precised: i am using nemo. It's a strange config for a low-spec vps for a customer

Comment: Try to use Thunar, by following these instructions (https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/custom-actions); try to make it working with Thunar. Maybe something will be connect also for Nemo file manager. I don't use Nemo, but Thunar has no problems

Comment: Suggestion: Note the version of Nemo and Xfce Terminal you are running (run `nemo --version` and `xfce4-terminal --version | head -n 1` in terminal) and include in your question.

Comment: The answer below should work. The idea is that Nemo is configured to work with `gnome-terminal`, which was not installed. Use the command in the answer replacing 'TERMINAL' with 'xfce4-terminal': `org.cinnamon.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec 'xfce4-terminal'` The same change can be done with dconf Editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this command:

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec 'TERMINAL'
```